# CakePHP SHOW FULL COLUMNS when debug 0

Tags: performance, debugging, cakephp

I would like to understand why CakePHP is calling SHOW FULL COLUMNS when debug level is set to 0. This is causing a huge performance impact on my database. I am running Cake 2.4.2 in my env.

Appreciate any advises.

Thanks,
Andre

Comment: I think it should do that only rarely, to get database schema information, and then cache it. Any chance that the permissions are wrong on your `tmp/cache/models` folder, so the cache write is failing?

Comment: Actually, there is no /tmp in my Cake installation. I do have a model folder at /app/tmp/cache/models, but its empty. Ive noticed that I have something at app/tmp/domains/<domain_Name>/cache/models. Is this cache path configurable?

Comment: Also, it seems that contents from app/tmp/domains/<domain_Name>/cache/models are being constantly updated. Last modified date and time from files are current.

Comment: I was able to figure out the problem. It was related to debug settings.